# parseFloat not changing string value in sql to float

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using node-mysql and have 2 rows. I am adding together the 'total' column which values are 1.10 and 1.16 obviously expecting total to be 2.26

I am querying the table, and the adding them as follows:

```
connection.query(q3, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var totalSum=0;
    for(i=0; i<results.length;i++) {
        totalSum = totalSum + parseFloat(results[i].total).toFixed(2);
    }
```

However my totalSum returns as 01.101.16 which shows as a concatenation of strings. Why is my parseFloat not changing the string obtained from sql?

Thanks

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a **string**, not a number.

Comment: try `Number(results[i])`

Comment: @maioman if the `.toFixed()` is still there that will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: Ha.. so simple. thanks will accept when it lets me

Comment: @Pointy I meant `Number( (results[i].total).toFixed(2) )` for converting it back to number  but OP shouldn't use `toFixed(2)`  to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to format the sum as a number with two places past the decimal point, do so *after* the total has been calculated. The `.toFixed()` function returns a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
totalSum = (totalSum + parseFloat(results[i].total)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Because `.toFixed(2)` will return a string, this will have exactly the same problem as the original.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) within the loop. It should be called on the sum.

```
let totalSum = results.reduce((prev,curr) => prev.total + curr.total).toFixed(2);
```